# How to talk about "vision problems " and "eye glasses "?

Tags: usage

How can we ask a person if one has a vision problems? and what is the other name for "eye glasses?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context, but informally you can ask

> How's your vision?

or

> How are your eyes?

I'm not sure about other countries, but in the US "good" vision is called "20/20".  So you can ask:

> Do you have 20/20 vision?

"Eyeglasses" are called that, or just "glasses".  So you can ask:

> Do you wear glasses?

A more formal way to ask this (such as on an insurance form) would be:

> Do you wear corrective lenses?

Comment: Many thanks. I hv also heard the word "power " while talking about vision n glasses. Any comments on it?

Comment: @AltafJahangir  There are a number of optometrist terms related to glasses which you would probably know well if you wear them (which I don't).  "Diopter" refers to the *refractive power* of the lenses, but you can sometimes use "power" to refer to the magnification of reading glasses (1.5x, 2x, 3x, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

**What is your vision?**

Also you can ask the following questions instead.

> How strong are your glasses?
>
> What is the power of your glasses?
>
> What is the strength of your glasses?

Comment: “What is your vision?" would be a good question if you are asking someone about their exact vision (e.g., “My vision is 20/20.”) However, that is not what the OP asked.